# Dynamic toggle switcher [Angular]

Tags: angular

I have a button which is a typical toggle switch. It moves left as well as right when you click on it. I want this button to move itself according to the value I have in the api. In the api I have a value such as is_value. Some elements have is_value true or false so it is a boolean. Depending on what that value is I would like the button to adjust according to that. How can something like this be achieved?

I am using a reactive form so ngModel cannot be

```
toggle = false;

toggleMethod() {
this.toggle = !this.toggle;
}
```

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isStatus" (click)="toggleMethod()">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I created a toggle variable equal to false and a method that toggles from false to true and vice versa. When I click on this button, it moves me to the right - it's true, I move it to the left - it's false and it does, however the button element does not toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind the model to your input component :

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isStatus" 
  [(ngModel)]="toggle">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

When you check/uncheck the checkbox, your property gets automatically updated.

EDIT : Just saw its a reactive form. Then try this :

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isStatus" 
  [checked]="toggle"
  (change)="toggle = !toggle">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: every button has the same place unfortunately